# How to remove value to the front of the data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like the `list.1`,there have too much NA, so I want to remove the value to the front of the data.frame ,through that I can drop the extra columns.
`list.1`

```
#  ID   col1     col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7
#1  1    2         3       NA      4     NA       NA     8
#2  2    3         NA      6       NA    6        NA    NA
#3  3    NA        2       NA      7     7         1     8
```

the result i want is:
`list.2`

```
#  ID   col1     col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7
#1  1    2         3       4      8      NA      NA     NA
#2  2    3         6       6      NA     NA      NA     NA
#3  3    2         7       7      1      8       NA     NA
```

so, i can drop the `col6` and`col7` to make the data.frame looks more better

Comment: So the columns mean nothing? Because otherwise you would change values where you should not. Imagine that each column stood for a specific months and the values for rainfall. Then it would be very wrong to simply overwrite the empty rainfall in June with rainfall from July.

Comment: Maybe a data.frame isn't the right format. What is the objective of your data?

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for reminding me.Actually I first split a column and then  dropped some values that were not needed that made  a lot of NA values. Each column has no substantial meaning, so the movement of values do not affect the data@Fnguyen @Jonny Phelps

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))

  ID col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1  1    2    3    4    8   NA   NA   NA
2  2    3    6    6   NA   NA   NA   NA
3  3    2    7    7    1    8   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Could I add an extra question:How do I change values in each column that are not belongs to c(1,2,3)  to NA

Comment: You can try `sapply(df[-1], function(x) replace(x, x <= 3, NA)) ` or `df[df <= 3] <- NA`.